# python str object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, string, list, loops, scramble

I'm trying to set the scrambled word from the list back to the list I have created, which is from `split`. I tried reading some of the solutions here and I think it's because you can't change the string in the list?

I'm not really sure correct me if I'm wrong :( . `the sentence[i] = temp_word` is giving the error. thanks in  advance :)

```
class WordScramble:
def __init__(self):
    self.user_input = input("Please give me a sentence: ")

def scramble(self):
    # print what was input
    print("The user input was: ", self.user_input)

    # first scramble is just one word
    print(self.user_input[0] + self.user_input[2] + self.user_input[1] + self.user_input[3:])

    # reverse two indices
    # particularly good to use is to switch the first two
    # and the last two
    # this only makes sense if you have a world that is longer than 3


    # now try to scramble one sentence
    sentence = self.user_input.strip().split(" ")

    for i, word in enumerate(sentence):
        if len(word) > 3:
            temp_word = list(word)
            if ',' in temp_word:
                temp = temp_word[1]
                temp_word[1] = temp_word[-3]
                temp_word[-3] = temp

            else:
                temp = temp_word[1]
                temp_word[1] = temp_word[2]
                temp_word[2] = temp

            temp_word = ''.join(temp_word)
            sentence[i] = temp_word
        sentence = ''.join(sentence)
        print(sentence)




    #print(" ".join(sentence))

    # do just words first, then you can move on to work on
    # punctuation

word_scrambler = WordScramble()
word_scrambler.scramble()
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error you received.

Comment: Also, avoid trying to manually fix indentation issues in pasted code. In Python in particular it tends to produce indentation errors and ambiguities. Paste the code in, select the entire code block, and type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the interface. Or just add triple backticks before and after the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because inside the for loop you wrote:

```
sentence = ''.join(sentence)
```

Thus, at the second iteration, the 'sentence' variable is now a string and in python, strings don't support item assignment as they are immutable variables. I think you meant to get this out of the for loop to print the final sentence.

Comment: Thanks so much this fixed the issue!!!  :))  so its basically meant to be outside because the sentence is already a string